# How to pass special character ('-' for example) as an argument in command line in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, special-characters

I need to run putty that automatically logs into a server. Unfortunately one of the servers has a minus sign in the password. It seems that command line interpret the minus in the password as the begin of next argument. How to avoid that interpretation?

I call sth like this:

`PATH_TO_PUTTY/putty.exe -ssh user@myadress.com -pw password-passwordend`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are right. For PuTTY, a dash (minus) does not have any special meaning, unless it is after a whitespace character. So for your example in the question, PuTTY will use password `password-passwordend`.

While I would not actually expect this, it may be your SSH server that misinterprets dashes in the password.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes and see if that makes it happy:

```
PATH_TO_PUTTY/putty.exe -ssh user@myadress.com -pw "password-passwordend"
```